# Разделение контроллера Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Приветствую, не могу найти ответ на мой вопрос.
Как правильно разделить контроллер `main`

Есть 2 роли пользователей и единственный на них контроллер, но `action` и `models` разные.
В голове такая схема:

`mainController` при инициализации проверяет роли пользователей, далее загружает **пользовательский class** с набором `action` для данной роли.
Такое возможно сделать? если да, то как правильнее?

P.S. участник на "toster" предложил вариант такой:

Один контроллер содержит в себе все `views` для всех ролей, даже если имена `views` повторяются, и в каждом из них проверять роль пользователя, подгружать модель и выводить `view`.

Мне такой вариант не нравится, ибо в будущем ролей пользователей станет много, и код будет ужасно громоздкий и не удобный.

Ищу вариант, чтобы разружить главный `mainController`. Один раз проверить роль пользователя, и уже на основе этого выводить все доступные ему `actions`

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сгруппировать действия по пользователю, но это неправильно. Действия будут перескаться, их будет бесконечно много, выделение их в отдельный класс сожрет много нервов и не принесет пользы. Вам в каждом действии надо проверять текущую роль и на основе ее выоплнять или не выполнять дальнейший код.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно ответил @Etki вы можете располагать экшены в любых контроллерах, на месте осуществляя проверку прав доступа.

Первый контроллер:

```
class AdministratorController extends Controller
{
    public function actionViewAdministratorPage()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->can('ViewAdministratorPage')) {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException('You are not allowed to do this action.');
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Второй контроллер

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function actionViewUserProfile()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->can('ViewUserProfile')) {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException('You are not allowed to do this action.');
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

В представлении определяйте на какие страницы пользователь имеет право заходить и отображайте только их. Также, для удобства управления можно не писать проверку в начале каждого экшена, а использовать [AccessControl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html).